# Why do I see the indication of a flagged message in chat?

Tags: support, chat, flags

Okay, so I know I sometimes get rowdy and misbehave in chat... but I guess somebody flagged me? Is that what I am understanding here?

[image: One flag but no flags?]

Is it saying I have *been* flagged once? Or I have flagged someone else once?

Why does it say I have 1 flags, but then below, "there are no flags to display"? Is this a contradiction?

Comment: I don't think it means you've been flagged - I see the same thing as you.  Seems there is a phantom flag.

Comment: @Rebecca A phantom flag? `/blame balpha`!

Comment: FWIW I no longer see this today...